# Accessing a placemark with google earth api through Region-Based Network Linked kml files

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I have a huge set of placemarks loaded using regionated kml files. (around 1000 kml files generated). 
For example , I have a button, when clicked camera flies to the location of the placemark I want to access. So I think the kml file that includes this placemark is loaded after this process. Let's say this is 5.kml and I tried to get the placemark object using getElementByUrl method. But this didn't work. I can also use ge.getElementsByType("KmlPlacemark") method but I need to have a loop to get the placemark object I need. This works but I couldn't find a way to make it work fast. Below is my code

```
google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getView(), 'viewchangeend', function() {                 
      // after button click and camera centered on the placemark with id 1767
      var p = ge.getElementByUrl('http://localhost/Test/5.kml#1767');
      alert(p.getId());  // this does not work because p is null
      var placemarks = ge.getElementsByType('KmlPlacemark'); 
      for (var i = 0; i < placemarks.getLength(); ++i) {
         var placemark = placemarks.item(i);
         if(placemark.getId() == 1767)
         {              
            alert(placemark.getId()); // this works      
            return;
         }
     }      
});

 function button_click()
{
    var camera = ge.getView().copyAsCamera(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
    camera.setLatitude(30);
    camera.setLongitude(50);
    camera.setAltitude(2000);
    ge.getView().setAbstractView(camera);   
  }
```

I wish I found a way to access the object which is imported from KML(when region beomes active). Waiting for your answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

NetworkLink's don't load files into the DOM, which is why `getElementByUrl` doesn't find the Placemark you're looking for. You would need to fetch the KML. [This article](http://code.google.com/apis/earth/articles/earthapikml.html) should be helpful in explaining the different ways to load KML in the Google Earth API.

Comment: My problem was a file access problem through IIS I guess. I've fixed it and my code works as I expected. The camera zooms to the placemark, so the kml file which includes that placemark is retrieved, then I can modify the style of my placemark. In the article it says you can't modify the loaded KML file **before** you display it, but currently it seems that I can change the style after loading KML and displaying the placemark. Nice article by the way.